# In-place make_unique with ADL support

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to learn templates better, so I wrote a small function for *in-place `unique_ptr`*. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

struct A {
    int a = 0;
    double b = 0.0;
    A() { std::cout << "c1\n"; }
    A(int a) : a(a) { std::cout << "c2\n"; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "d\n"; }
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
auto make_unique(void *p, Args&&... args) {
    return std::unique_ptr<T, std::function<void(T*)>>(
                     new(p) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...), 
                     [](T* ptr) { ptr->~T(); });
};

int main() {
    std::array<char,50> buf1;
    std::array<char,50> buf2;

    auto o1 = make_unique<A>(buf1.data());
    auto o2 = make_unique<A>(buf2.data(), 3);
}
```

This code works as I expect and calls constructor/destructor when object lifetime finishes in a *in-place* fashion.

But here is my problem. I like to use it as ADL (Argument-dependent lookup), but when I add `using std::make_unique;` to the top of code, code compiles with error. It seems this happens because compiler cannot distinguish between my `make_unique()` and what is specified in libraries. I guess it conflicts with this one:

```
template< class T, class... Args >
unique_ptr<T> make_unique( Args&&... args );
```

I wonder if it is a way to make this work out? or the simplest way is renaming my `make_unique()` to another function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std make unique does not test in a SFINAE/overload-friendly way if its arguments can be used to make the object.  Even if it did your plan would be bad, as placement new and non-placement new should not depend on delecate overload selection.  They are very different operations.

So a few improvements:

```
template<class T>
auto placement_unique(void *p) {
  return [p](auto&&...args) {
    return std::unique_ptr<T, void(*)(T*)>(
                 ::new(p) T(decltype(args)(args)...), 
                 +[](T* ptr) { ptr->~T(); }
    );
  };
};
```

Use is:

```
auto pa = placement_unique<A>(ptr)( 7 );
```

like placement new, the pointer and object arguments are split.

This can be further improved:

```
struct destroy_it {
  template<class T>
  void operator()(T* t)const { if (t) t->~T(); }
};

template<class T>
using unique_placed_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, destroy_it>;
template<class T>
auto placement_unique(void *p) {
  return [p](auto&&...args) {
    return unique_placed_ptr<T>(
                 ::new(p) T(decltype(args)(args)...)
    );
  };
};
```

this requires 0 more memory than a standard `unique_ptr` -- the deleter is stateless.  It is even common between different `unique_ptr` types.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion, but 2 questions:1- is `decltype(args)(args)...` better than `std::forward` for this situation? 2- what is that `+` before lambda's capture list?

Comment: oh, and another one: how `auto&&args` in returned lambda's argument list shows variadic arguments?

Comment: @afshin we don't have a type, so we need decltype to extract it.  And in this case decltype returns exactly the right cast.  `+` converts the lambda into a function pointer.

Comment: @afsh that was a missing `...` tpyo

Comment: so it should not be like this: `std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...`? if we like to use forward behavior too?

Comment: @Afshin Forward is a conditional move -- it either moves, or casts-to-itself.  A move is a cast, to an rvalue reference.  `decltype(args)(args)...` is also a cast.  `decltype(args)(args)...` is the same as `std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...` except about half as long, so long as `args` are variables of forwarding reference type.  In the case where `args` are not variables of forwarding reference type, `std::forward` makes a difference; that difference is sometimes desired, but not relevant here.